# Isn't this a dangling something?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, modifiers

> As one of the busiest times of year, people will share moments, plan for the festivities and search for the perfect gift, every single day — on Facebook. And this year, it will truly be a mobile holiday season.

I came across this little piece of text on facebook business. English is not my native language, so I have a little trouble putting a handle on what it is that bugs me so much about this sentence. The beginning of the sentence does not seem to connect at all with the subject.... right?

Comment: Hello Nekoeko, and welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 3):

You're quite right. It is very awkwardly written.

I suppose it's a kind of dangling modifier (but it is 4:20 AM, so my mental faculties may not be functioning at full capacity). It certainly shares the [salient feature of a dangling modifier](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier), in that it is easily

> misinterpreted as being associated with a word other than the one intended, or with no particular word at all

From the context, it is clear that the phrase “as one of the busiest times of year” is in fact supposed to be associated with the word *Christmas*—except there's no actual mention of Christmas. The only thing it can logically attach itself to is *people*, which is clearly nonsense. People are not a time of year, busy or otherwise.

Comment: 'As' should be 'Christmas being' (though 'This being' works if it's obvious that we're in the Christmas period, and even 'At' if it's very obvious  what we're talking about).